# Emulating a sentinel c-plus security dongle to attach to a virtual machine

Tags: hardware, virtual-machines, dongle

My company has an ancient payroll system that we want to virtualise so that it can be preserved for legal reasons. The software runs on an operating system called [THEOS](http://www.theos-software.com/).

We've run into a bit of a snag. The operating system depends on a security dongle being present to install and run. The device is a sentinel C-Plus A (see below). It connects to a parallel port and acts a passthrough device for a parallel printer.

[image: Sentinel C-Plus A]

I've been exploring options on how to virtualise this dongle. My plan is to somehow emulate the dongle, attach the virtual device to VMware machine and install THEOS as a VM (I already know THEOS is compatible with VMware).

So far, I've managed to find [this forum](http://forum.exetools.com/showthread.php?t=10992) which is hosting a dumper and emulator for this dongle, but I'm not able to download it as I'm not a member (and cannot join without an invite code).

I've also found [this business](http://www.dongleservice.com/emulate-sentinel-cplus.phtml) that claims to be able to create an emulator for this dongle, and am in the process of contacting them about it. However, we would prefer to do this ourselves rather than go through someone else.

Does anyone have any advice or experience for a situation like this? Or perhaps information on how we can access the tools hosted on the exeforums site?

Comment: Have you tried contacting theos about this? They might supply an official solution, which has the benefit of not breaking any licenses and come with a vendor guarantee that it'll continue to work long-term.

Comment: From http://www.theos-software.com/reasons.pdf - "a physical or virtual dongle is required for every THEOS machine". So yes, as @GuntramBlohm suggested, contact the vendor :)

Comment: Yeah, I have tried contacting theos. I did get a response from them about the fact that theos could be virtualised, but I haven't managed to hear back from them about the security dongle yet. @JasonGeffner Interesting; I hadn't seen the word 'virtual dongle' in the other documentation I was looking at. This gives me some hope; I'll push the vendors harder.

Comment: Just heard back from THEOS; no dice. The response was that USB dongles are supported, but not virtual devices. We will persist with attempting to emulate our dongle as we would rather not depend on specific hardware to preserve this system (other than our ESXi host)

Comment: QUESTION: Has there been any update on this? I ask b/c I'm in a situation where I need to "transport" my THEOS server and I can't seem to get the virtual machine to see the physical dongles (I have both a USB and LPT version). I thought it was my VM setup, but everything seems right there. Thanks.

Comment: We never ended up resolving this ourselves. We got a quote from a guy in our area who had done virtualization of THEOS before, but never went ahead with it. I think the quote was for about 4-5k AUD for the conversion. Apparently you need some specific hardware in order to get it working properly.

Comment: Understand this is an old post but are you looking to use an add-on parallel port on perhaps the PCIe or PCI bus and still continue to use this dongle? If yes, we have supported this and other dongles in the past. We are a manufacturer of add-on parallel port adapters and do offer support on Windows, Linux, DOS, VMWare and other obscure OS including SCO Unix.

Comment: Depends entirely what the dongle does. Cracked a Sentinel dongle ages ago. But that was literally _ages_ ago in IT terms. Talking nearly twenty years. The way I did it was to write a filter driver which would listen in. It would also double to extract the key material. I doubt this sort of weakness persists after nearly twenty years ... alas in my case the protected software was running on Windows. Being a whole OS makes this somewhat harder, I guess.